# tflearn.DNN:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit'

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, tflearn

when running the code below, error in title line appears.

```
            model = tflearn.DNN(network,tensorboard_verbose=0, checkpoint_path='classifier.tfl.ckpt')
```

It seems the problem is with tf.DNN. Traceback as follows.

```
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/may/PycharmProjects/cnn/cnn.py", line 67, in <module>
                model = tflearn.DNN(network,tensorboard_verbose=0,checkpoint_path='classifier.tfl.ckpt')
              File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py", line 64, in __init__
                best_val_accuracy=best_val_accuracy)
              File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 131, in __init__
                clip_gradients)
              File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 616, in initialize_training_ops
                self.validation_monitors_T = [tf.Variable(0., name='%s_T' % v.name.rsplit(':', 1)[0], trainable=False) for v in self.validation_monitors]
            AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit'
```

Comment: in addition to the error, do you have a traceback?

Comment: @tiwo, the traceback is added in the questions now. I deleted some arguement in the tflearn.DNN function but the same error still exists. Thanks.